# Jest/Redux: How to test frontend function that accesses backend

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, redux

I'm learning to unit test using Jest on a front end that uses javascript. There are several functions that use a backend object to get our data/run logic and I'm wondering how I can test these functions without access to the backend. Below is the general idea of a function.

```
export function func(param1, param2) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(someFunc());

    Backend.func(param1, param2)
      .catch(() => {
        dispatch(errorFunc());
      })
      .then(() => {
        dispatch(successFunc());
      });
  };
}
```

The backend object doesn't do anything as I'm not connected, so when testing the function my mock store only receives the someFunction action. What do I have available to make a mock backend and is there a way to inject this so it runs the mock backend when I test the function instead of the real one?

edit: So I've kind of narrowed down what I want to do. The Backend is in its own script, and we have a FakeBackend which has the same interface. Is there a way to redirect Backend to actually call FakeBackend?

Comment: You can mock your backend to just return some results. Or you could mock a node server if you use karma there are some plugins/frameworks.

Comment: I guess my question is how is this done. Like the Backend function call is inside the action function I'm testing. Is there something I can do to redirect it to a mocked object so Backend is now my mocked object? I'm pretty new to Jest/unit testing in general so I've had trouble figuring out what to search for.

Comment: Look into [sinon](http://sinonjs.org/) for a mocking lib.